LangChain Sequential Chaining with LCEL
I'm currently envisioning to build a kind of writing engine to automate iterations and prompts I would have done manually before. For this, I would like to use OpenAI + LangChain.
I read a lot and have a "working" prototype but still struggle to understand if it's the right way as there are a lot of changes and outdated repos/docs out there.
I understand that there is a way using SequentialChain and SimpleSequentialChain, but for me it looks like this depends on the Chains module/class (e.g., LLMChain) which is perceived legacy (according to LangChain): https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/chains/
That's why I'm trying to use LCEL with a combination of RunnablePassthrough:
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.schema import StrOutputParser
from langchain.schema.runnable import RunnablePassthrough

context = "I run a blog; I address a semi-technical audience on LinkedIn; my writing style uses commonly understandable language to make it sound like a personal blog post using anecdotes and jokes while keeping an overall professional tone"
goal = "be as creative as possible; take my initial ideas and augment, optimize given the context above; function as my creative writing assistant"
topic = "Data & AI"
thoughts = "Data & AI related stuff"

structure_prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(
    """You are a writer. Given the following insights you are tasked with brainstorming a structure for a new blog post; be creative, add things I might have not considered and build a structure for an informative yet engaging blog post
    Context: {context}
    Goal: {goal}
    Topic: {topic}
    Thoughts: {thoughts}
    """
)

review_prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(
    """You are an expert reviewer. Given this drafted structure for a blog post, what would you optimize; what would you add, focus or remove given the context, topic and thoughts explained above:
    Structure: {structure}
    Provide concrete feedback in a cohesive and comprehensive form that a writer can optimize the original sturcture accordingly.
    """
)

optimization_prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(
    """You are a writer. Optimize the following blog post structure given the feedback review provided.
    Structure: {structure}
    Review: {review}
    """
)

llm = ChatOpenAI()

structure_chain = structure_prompt | llm | StrOutputParser()
review_chain = review_prompt | llm | StrOutputParser()
optimization_chain = optimization_prompt | llm | StrOutputParser()

chain = ({"structure" : structure_chain} 
        | RunnablePassthrough.assign(review=review_chain)
        | RunnablePassthrough.assign(optimization=optimization_chain))

result = chain.invoke({"context": context, "goal" : goal, "topic" : topic, "thoughts" : thoughts})

As mentioned, the prototype works and produces the intended results…but I struggle to understand if this is the right way forward…
